# Double with specific format and two decimals

Tags: java, decimal

I'm trying to format the numbers to look like a certain way.

So, I have like the number **1007,2**, and I want it to look like **1 007,20**

This has two factors needed:

- Thousands format
- Two decimal places

I have a code that sets the thousands format:

```
Double total_value = Double.valueOf(1007,2);

String formatedValue = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH).format(total_value);
```

And the output is:
**1 007,2€**

And I have the code for the two decimal places:

```
Double total_value = Double.valueOf(1007,2);

String formatedValue = String.format("%.2f", total_value);
```

The problem is, for using this two format methods at the same time they get always problems, because the two of them return Strings, and both need to receive the values for formatting in Double.

If I receive one in String, when I try to parse the String to Double like `String value = Double.parseDouble(formatedValue);`or `String value = Double.valueOf(formatedValue)` they always get an error. I've already tried the **DecimalFormat** to but it returns a String too.

So, I dont know how to do to conjugue the two methods to work together!

If you have any idea please comment it :)

Comment: Have you tried dealing separately with the numerical and decimal part then concatenating the results (removing the two first characters of the decimal string)?

Comment: Note, `Double.valueOf(1007,2);` doesn't compile. Although we can guess what you meant, it's best to copy/paste real code into your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to combine `NumberFormat` and `String.format()`.

---

You can further configure your `NumberFormat` object to tell it to use two decimal places:

```
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    assertThat(numberFormat.format(1007.2), is("1 007,20"));
```

(and possibly `setMaximumFractionDigits()` etc., depending on your needs -- see the Javadoc)

Take care - `NumberFormat.format()` is not thread-safe.

---

Alternatively you can use `String.format(locale, format, args)`:

```
 assertThat(String.format(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, "%,.2f", 1007.2), is("1 007,20"));
```

The `,` flag in the format tells the formatter to use a thousands-separator, and the locale tells it that the separator is a space.

Comment: It's working really well the first option! Thank you so muuch :)

Answer (score 0):

After setting the thousand format you could do someting like:

```
String[] splitter = formatedValue.split("\\,");
int decimalDigits = 0;
if (splitter.length > 1) {
    formatedValue = splitter[1].length();
} else {
    formatedValue += ",";
}
for (int i = 0; i < 2 - decimalDigits; i++) {
    formatedValue += "0";
}
```

I have not tested this, and it is not the really pretty, but i am using something similar for the english format.

To make sure you have only two decimal digits you should probably round your total value at the beginning.